# Json communication between flash and javascript

Tags: python, flash, json

note: using django/python/javascript/flash

So its been two days since I'm stuck at the error. I did the things you told me to and found a couple of ways around it but nothing worked. These are the results.

Javascript does not receive the normal string it has to be a json object so. in views.py

```
somestring = json.dumps("HELLO WORLD")
```

which renders this in HTML

```
&quot;HELLO WORLD&quot;
```

and in javascript it is rendered like this

```
a240527176321_quote_hello
```

Now, since it is a json object I need to convert it back in flash. But when it gets in flash where I receive it like this

```
function something(hellovar){
.....
......
}
```

it does not even come inside the function. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you communicate between flash and js via json? actionscript has a very powerfull build in [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_de/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to communicate with javascript.

Comment: I am using a localconnection to communicate the main problem is this in this line. It works fine for everything else.

   function sendScoreList(test){
                           testtext={{varsomething}}
                           document.getElementById('leaderboard_swf').callSWF('asMethod',testtext);   
   }


where varsomething comes from the server